# C# - Utilização de Certificado A3 (Leitor Cartão) + Windows Service

Tags: c#, criptografia, nfe, certificado-digital, windows-service

Bom dia a todos.

Criei um serviço windows (C#) onde assino os XML de NFC-es utilizando a DLL da FlexDocs. Utilizando o certificado A1 tudo funciona normalmente, **mas ao utilizar o A3, o frame onde devo digitar o PIN (senha) não abre/aparece.**

Procurei me informar via web, sobre este assunto e o que pude levantar é que, o  serviço windows não abre o frame pois não tem interação com usuário. Tentei então passar o PIN diretamente, mas mesmo assim não consegui.

Venho desesperamente aqui perguntar: **Existe alguma forma de utilizar Certificado A3 + Windows Service? De forma que fique 100% automático? Ou pelo menos passar o PIN via código???** O objetivo é simples, o serviço monitorar as informações dos cupons no BD e com isso gerar/assinar/enviar/buscar o XML.

Irei passar todas as informações que tenho até o momento:

1) O leitor de cartão é da **Serasa Experian**, modelo: **"Perto CCID"**;

2) Utilizando certificado A1 (arquivo instalável) funcionou 100%. A unica diferença é que tive que mudar o serviço para fazer logon como o usuário atual da maquina (Se possível gostaria que não tivesse que ser feito isso, mas como "conta do sistema" ou "conta serviço local" não funciona o certificado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Via Debug no Visual Studio, o certificado A3 abre o frame pra digitação do PIN, mas testando o serviço instalado, o mesmo não abre o frame do PIN e retorna: **5002 - Erro: Falha na conexão: Mensagem Erro do Windows=[A solicitação foi anulada: Não foi possível criar um canal seguro para SSL/TLS.] (Causa provável: a cadeia de certificação do Web Service acessado ou do certificado cliente inexistente no repositório de certificados do usuário corrente do Windows)**;

4)
tentei passar o PIN direto como explicado [aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/e11884e4-5c4c-4930-8fc6-1a3d0a68d382/certificado-a3-e-windows-service?forum=504), utilizando a classe "RSACryptoServiceProvider" mas está dando **"acesso negado"**. No código onde está "xxxx" => PIN. A linha de código que da erro de acesso negado => empresa.X509Certificado.PrivateKey = teste;:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

                //if (store.Certificates.Count == 0)
                //{
                //    store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                //    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                //}

                X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
                X509Certificate2Collection collection1 = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, empresa.Certificado.ToString().Trim(), false);

                if (collection1.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Não é possível continuar, Certificado Digital não encontrado!");
                }
                else
                {
                    empresa.X509Certificado = collection1[0];
                }

                RSACryptoServiceProvider teste = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                teste = LerDispositivo("xxxx", 1, "SafeSign Standard Cryptographic Service Provider");

                empresa.X509Certificado.PrivateKey = teste;
```

Qualquer Ajuda será bem vinda, se precisar de mais informações, por favor me pedir! Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 2):

A utilização do certificado do tipo A3 é mais restrita que o tipo A1. No A1, você pode abrí-lo dentro do código se tiver a senha da chave privada. No A3, é obrigatoriamente necessário que o usuário digite a senha quando ela for solicitada pela aplicação.

Quando você debuga o serviço no Visual Studio, ele está rodando na verdade como um Console e o "driver" do certificado vai mostrar a tela para digitar o PIN. Mas quando vira um Serviço Windows de verdade, o "driver" não vai deixar você usar o certificado.

Comment: Paulo Pires, muito obrigado pela resposta. Resolvi o problema fazendo um projeto C# de Windows Form mesmo... e mantendo o mesmo oculto e sem poder fechar pelo usuario, apenas pelo gerenciador de tarefas. O pessoal aqui da empresa concordoou em ser assim. Hoje nosso "serviço" NFCe já está em fase final de testes!

Comment: Show de bola @YanPatrick. Boa sorte!